Generate Telegram Bot only using API
Is there any possible way, to generate the bot for the Telegram without using the botfather? For example I need the functionality, when the user creates the account and automatically creates the bot for himself.
I have tried using the telegram library for Node.JS https://www.npmjs.com/package/telegram , but the main problem is to insert this verification code inside the code.
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { TelegramClient } from 'telegram';
import { StringSession } from 'telegram/sessions';
import input from 'input';
import { ConfigService } from '@nestjs/config';
import { error } from 'console';

@Injectable()
export class TelegramBotCreatorService {
  private apiId: number;
  private apiHash: string;
  private stringSession = new StringSession('');
  private readonly configService: ConfigService;

  constructor() {
    this.configService = new ConfigService();

    this.apiId = +this.configService.get<number>('TELEGRAM_API_ID');
    this.apiHash = this.configService.get<string>('TELEGRAM_API_HASH');
  }

  async createBot() {
    const client = new TelegramClient(this.stringSession, this.apiId, this.apiHash, {
      connectionRetries: 5,
    });

    await client.start({
      phoneNumber: 'XXXXXXXXXX',
      phoneCode: async () => {
        const code = await input.text('Enter the code you received: ');
        return code
      },
      onError: error => {
        console.log(error);
      },
    });

    console.log('You should now be connected.');
    console.log(client.session.save()); // Save this string to avoid logging in again
    await client.sendMessage('me', { message: 'Hello!' });
  }
}

Can I avoid it somehow, or could I use other library or turn off the code verification. Because the main idea is to make the bot instead of user for the user. I will be very appreciated for your help

I think you did not understand a concept of 'telegram bot' and 'telegram api' correctly.
As a developer we can work on telegram in two ways, telegram bot and telegram client.

Telegram Bots: These are special accounts that do not require an additional phone number to set up and These accounts serve as an interface for code running somewhere on your server.

Telegram Api: This is allows you to build your own customized Telegram clients


So to answer your questions

Can create telegram bot without @BotFather ?
Answer: No, every telegram bot need a Token for authentication and Each bot has a unique token which can also be revoked at any time via @BotFather. So telegram uses @BotFather for Authentication the bot and there is no way to remove this step.

What is node telegram library do?
Answer: This library use Telegram Api to create telegram client so in every telegram clones you should take authorize verification's code


Please see this links for more info
Telegram Api Docs
Telegram Bots Tutorial

Thank you for your answer, but I suppose, you didn't understand my concept. I know, that there are no way to generate the bot without the botfather, but I can generate bots using the Telegram API calling the botfather via API and then use the generated token from the botfather to assign but to the specified user. This is the main idea from stackoverflow

@Val there is no way to change the bot ownership, you can get user's bot token and then programming your bot with that token ?
is this useful?

I don't need to do this. I will create the account only for this purpose and user will receive the access to his bot, directly from the API, that is related to this account

if you use one account for all users bots, it's ok and you can create this account with your number and be the interface of @botfather but if you think to create a user for every user it can't be possible and its illogical

Yep, I use one account for all bots

I meant one account for all users

Finally, it is not possible to create a Telegram account without authentication, even with the Telegram API


I understood) I know. And about authentication I am using the session id of the authenticated session

maybe you know how to emulate the buttons interaction?
